# Does facebook web app need access token for reading likes of friend status

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to read likes on my friend's status. It is working fine if i copy the access token from the [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/214109771989025/?method=GET&path=100001021393791?fields=id,name).
If i use the getAccessToken method. It just returns an array with the id of the status, which was passed by me.

Can anybody help me on how to pass the access tokens to the app.

You may say that why don't you continue with the token copied from graph explorer?
But due to the recent changes offline_access token has been removed, so that the token is expiring for every hour. By the way i'm using graph api with php.

Answer (score 1):

The app needs a user access token if the status is not public – otherwise the API can not detect whether the current user is allowed to see it or not.

Get a long-lived access token: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for your quick response.
I'm sure that the status is public and specified that i'm getting it if i uses the token present in the graph explorer.

I'm not getting it, if i uses getAccessToken()

Comment: Thnq CBroe i got it. Taking the tokens in the app dashboard solved my problem 
and migration doesn't works in my case as mine is a webapp.
But very happy to know about this migration :)